# How could I get the interval after a qcut?

Tags: python, pandas, function, jupyter-notebook, binning

I just used a qcut function on my dataframe but I would like to find the best way to get the spread (interquantile) for each bin.

for example if I have [1000,2746] I would like to get 1746.

Thanks,

Comment: Sorry, what is the logic of getting `1746` from the closed interval `[1000, 2746]`?

Comment: It's really unclear what your actually looking for, you've mentioned "interval" in the title, "interquartile" in the question and what looks like the "range" in your expected output...but in general for range, `qcut` categories are just intervals, which have a `length` attribute, so assuming you have something like `q = pd.qcut(...)`, you can do `{i:i.length for i in q.cat.categories}`

Comment: Hello sorry I'm not a native english speaker my goal is to identy the biggest spread in my binning.